# Hibernate hazelcast second level cache inconsistency

Tags: java, hibernate, hazelcast, second-level-cache

In our project we are using hazelcast 3.6.5 as hibernate (4.3.11) second lvl cache.

Here is test which describes problem we are facing:

```java
@Test
public void cacheTest() {

    // Step 1: create account with someValue=111
    Account account = account().withName("test hz account").withSomeValue(111).build();
    account = restClient.upsertAccount(account);

    //Step 2: create user with ref to account
    User user = user().withAccount(account).build();
    restClient.upsertUser(user);

    //Step 3: update account someValue to 222
    account.setSomeValue(222);
    restClient.upsertAccount(account);

    //search users by account id
    List<User> users = restClient.searchUsersByAccountId(BRAND, account.getId());

    assertThat(users.size(), is(1));
    //assertion below fails, user.account.someValue=111
    assertThat(users.get(0).getAccount().getSomeValue(), is(222));
}
```

test is run on application with two nodes. Here is how requests are balanced to different nodes:

**node1**:

```
172.20.0.1 - - [12:30:46 +0200] "POST /accounts/BRAND/ HTTP/1.1" 200 321
172.20.0.1 - - [12:30:47 +0200] "POST /accounts/BRAND/ HTTP/1.1" 200 321
```

**node2**:

```
172.20.0.1 - - [12:30:47 +0200] "POST /users/BRAND/ HTTP/1.1" 200 542
172.20.0.1 - - [12:30:48 +0200] "POST /users/BRAND/search?start=0&limit=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 617
```

***I have found that hazelcast 2nd lvl cache contains two instances of same account***. One with old field value 111 and one with new one 222.

First instance is added to cache on first account insert, and second on user insert (we have account get call on user insert). As I understand these two account instances in cache causes inconsistency.

Any ideas why this could happen and how to debug this issue?

Here is data model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
@Cache(usage = READ_WRITE)
public class Account extends BrandIdEntity {
     @Column(name = "name")
     private String name;

     @Column(name = "some_value")
     private Integer someValue;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Cache(usage = READ_WRITE)
public class User extends BrandIdEntity {

    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private String accountId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = ALL)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "brand", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Account account;
}

@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "pk", callSuper = false)
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BrandIdEntity extends AuditedEntity<BrandIdPK> {

    @EmbeddedId
    private final BrandIdPK pk;

    public BrandIdEntity() {
        super();
        pk = new BrandIdPK();
    }

    public BrandIdEntity(BrandType brand, String id, IdGenType idGenType) {
        super();
        pk = new BrandIdPK(brand, id, idGenType);
    }
}

@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BrandIdPK extends BaseObject {

    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "brand")
    private String brand;

    public BrandIdPK(BrandType brand, String id, IdGenType idGenType) {
        this.brand = brand.name();
        if (id != null) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        else {
            this.id = next(idGenType);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is hazelcast map config:

```
{
   name='com.project.data.Account',
   inMemoryFormat='BINARY',
   backupCount=1,
   asyncBackupCount=0,
   timeToLiveSeconds=300,
   maxIdleSeconds=0,
   evictionPolicy='LRU',
   evictionPercentage=25,
   minEvictionCheckMillis=100,
   maxSizeConfig=MaxSizeConfig{maxSizePolicy='PER_NODE',size=100000},
   readBackupData=true,
   hotRestart=HotRestartConfig{enabled=false,fsync=false},
   nearCacheConfig=null,
   mapStoreConfig=MapStoreConfig{
      enabled=false,className='null',factoryClassName='null',writeDelaySeconds=0,writeBatchSize=1,
      implementation=null,factoryImplementation=null,properties={},
      readOnly=null,initialLoadMode=LAZY,writeCoalescing=true
   },
   mergePolicyConfig='com.hazelcast.map.merge.PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy',
   wanReplicationRef=null,
   entryListenerConfigs=[],
   mapIndexConfigs=[],
   mapAttributeConfigs=[],
   quorumName=null,
   queryCacheConfigs=[],
   cacheDeserializedValues=INDEX_ONLY
}
```

Comment: Probably a stupid question but have both instances joined the same cluster? Apart from that I'm not sure what's causing this but I could imagine that the logic tries to use the generated hashcode/equals methods which are not utilized by Hazelcast.

Comment: hazelcast cluster is ok. I posted my problem also on hibernate forum: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1044970&start=0&sid=1499880a5d5744697fa59129e961c84a.

Comment: i am going to update to latest hazelcast/hibernate versions and make hazelcast to use custom keys, because problem is with serialization of hibernate CacheKey

Comment: What is the problem? What I said before?